# What is the resistivity coefficient of  graphene?

Tags: graphene

What is the resistivity coefficient of  graphene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphene has a high electron mobility at ordinary room temperature. Experiments also has shown that the conductivity of electron and holes are almost the same. Between the temperature 10 to 100 k it is independent of temperature. At room temperature the resistivity is $10 ^{-6}$ ohmcm. There is a good [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) for more information.

Comment: Are You shure that electric specific resistance is what Alaukik wants to know?